# Locating tags in a string in PHP (with respect to the string with tags removed)

Tags: php, string, pytorch, label, italics

I want to create a function that labels the location of certain HTML tags (e.g., italics tags) in a string with respect to the locations of characters in a tagless version of the string.
(I intend to use this label data to train a neural network for tag recovery from data that has had the tags stripped out.)
The magic function I want to create is `label_italics()` in the below code.

```
$string = 'Disney movies: <i>Aladdin</i>, <i>Beauty and the Beast</i>.';
$string_all_tags_stripped_but_italics = strip_tags($string, '<i>'); // same as $string in this example
$string_all_tags_stripped = strip_tags($string); // 'Disney movies: Aladdin, Beauty and the Beast.'
$featr_string = $string_all_tags_stripped.' '; // Add a single space at the end
$label_string = label_italics($string_all_tags_stripped_but_italics);
echo $featr_string; // 'Disney movies: Aladdin, Beauty and the Beast. '
echo $label_string; // '0000000000000001000000101000000000000000000010'
```

If a character is supposed to have an `<i>` or `</i>` tag immediately preceding it, it is labeled with a 1 in `$label_string`; otherwise, it is labeled with a 0 in `$label_string`.  (I'm thinking I don't need to worry about the difference between `<i>` and `</i>` because the recoverer will simply alternate between `<i>` and `</i>` so as to maintain well-formed markup, but I'm open to reasons as to why I'm wrong about this.)

I'm just not sure what the best way to create `label_italics()` is.

I wrote this function that seems to work in most cases, but it also seems a little clunky and I'm posting here in hopes that there is a better way.  (If this turns out to be the best way, the below function would be easily generalizable to any HTML tag passed in as a second argument to the function, which could be renamed `label_tag()`.)

```
function label_italics($stripped) {
  while ((stripos($stripped, '<i>') || stripos($stripped, '</i>')) !== FALSE) {
    $position = stripos($stripped, '<i>');
    if (is_numeric($position)) {
      for ($c = 0; $c < $position; $c++) {
        $output .= '0';
      }
      $output .= '1';
    }
    $stripped = substr($stripped, $position + 4, NULL);
    $position = stripos($stripped, '</i>');
    if (is_numeric($position)) {
      for ($c = 0; $c < $position; $c++) {
        $output .= '0';
      }
      $output .= '1';
    }
    $stripped = substr($stripped, $position + 5, NULL);
  }
  for ($c = 0; $c <= strlen($stripped); $c++) {
    $output .= '0';
  }
  return $output;
}
```

The function produces bad output if the tags are surplus or the markup is badly formed in the input.  For example, for the following input:

```
$string = 'Disney movies: <i><i>Aladdin</i>, <i>Beauty and the Beast</i>.';
```

The following misaligned output is given.

```
Disney movies: Aladdin, Beauty and the Beast.
0000000000000001000000000101000000000000000000010
```

(I'm also open to reasons why I'm going about the creation of the label data all wrong.)

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got something. How about this:

```
function label_italics($string) {
    return preg_replace(['/<i>/', '/<\/i>/', '/[^#]/', '/##0/', '/#0/'], 
                        ['#', '#', '0', '2', '1'], $string);
}
```

see: https://3v4l.org/cKG46

Note that you need to supply the string with the tags in it.

**How does it work?**

I use [preg_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) because it can use regular expressions, which I need once. This function goes through the two arrays and execute each replacement in order. First it replace all occurrences of `<i>` and `</i>` by `#` and anything else by `0`. Then replaces `##0` by `2` and `#0` by `1`. The `2` is extra to be able to replace `<i></i>`. You can remove it, and simplify the function, if you don't need it.

The use of the `#` is arbitrary. You should use anything that doesn't clash with the content of your string.

---

Here's an updated version. It copes with tags at the end of the line and it ignores any `#` characters in the line.

```
function label_italics($string) {
    return preg_replace(['/[^<\/i\>]/', '/<i>/', '/<\/i>/', '/i/', '/##0/', '/#0/'], 
                        ['0', '#', '#', '0', '2', '1'], $string . ' ');
}
```

See: https://3v4l.org/BTnLc

Comment: That's pretty good.  Your function should have as a first line appending a space to the end of the input string, otherwise it returns output like `00000000000000020000001010000000000000000000#` if the string ends with a closing tag.  I'm not sure what character would best be used, though, in place of the pound symbol `#`, to ensure it would never clash with the input.  It's possible that the input could be anything usually found in text.

Comment: @RobertKS Both problems can be overcome I think. I didn't test a tag at the end, but I think you can solve that problem yourself. As to the `#` I use, I agree that this could be a weakness. There is a solution however. You could start by replacing every character that is not a `<`, `i`, `>` or `/`. I think the regular expression for that would be `/[^<\/i\>]/`. After that it is perfectly safe to use the `#` character. OK, I tried something. Here's an updated version: https://3v4l.org/BTnLc

Comment: The updated version is pretty good but doesn't work on three tags in a row: input `Disney movies: <i><i><i>Aladdin</i>, <i>Beauty and the Beast</i>` gives `000000000000000#200000010100000000000000000001`.  Anyway, you've given me some ideas and I can continue to work on it.  Thanks.

Comment: @RobertKS I think it is pretty obvious how you can cope with 3 tags in a row. Just extend what I did with 1 tag and 2 tags.

Comment: @RobertKS By wanting to work with multiple sequential tags you're now going beyond the premise of your question. Other things to think about is case sensitivity: `<I>uppercase</I>`, or attributes: `<i class="fun">I enjoy this</i>`. The first is pretty easy to deal with, the second is a lot more difficult.

Comment: Modification of the updated version that solves the problems of multiple tags in a row and case sensitivity: `preg_replace(['/[^<\/i\>]/', '/<i>/', '/<\/i>/', '/i/', '/(#)\1+0/', '/#0/'], ['0', '#', '#', '0', '1', '1'], strtolower($string).' ')`

Answer (score 0):

After some additional experimentation, this is what I arrived at:

`$label_string = mb_ereg_replace('#0', '1', mb_ereg_replace('(#)\1+0', '1', mb_ereg_replace('\/', '0', mb_ereg_replace('i', '0', mb_ereg_replace('<\/i>', '#', mb_ereg_replace('<i>', '#', mb_ereg_replace('[^<\/i\>]', '0', mb_strtolower($featr_string))))))));`

I couldn't get @KIKO Software's preg_replace()-based solution to work with multibyte strings.  So I changed to this slightly ungainly, but better-operative, mb_ereg_replace()-based solution instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).